# Смена картинки заднего фона при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html

я хочу чтобы при нажатии на кнопку менялась картинка заднего фона страницы , и чтобы это работало через localhost,  так как document.getElementById().style.backgroundImage  в localhost не срабатывает.

Answer (score 0):

Положите ваше изображение в ту же директорию, либо в поддиректорию каталога, где вы запускаете ваш проект. Пусть к нему введите так, как я указал ниже.

```
 document.getElementById("id").style.backgroundImage = 'url(\''+/yourImage.jpg + '\')';
```